# What difference between 'Link binaries with libraries' and 'Libary Search Path' in Xcode project setting

Tags: xcode

What the difference between 'Link binaries with libraries' and 'Libary Search Path' in Xcode project settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Library Search Path` is the location **where** to search for your library files.

`Link binaries` is **what** the library or framework your project will link to.

Comment: Does it mean that it will link the searched library file?

Comment: No，if you using the framework manually,you need to set the library search path so that Xcode will know where to find your framework. It just search,not add.

Comment: Are there any difference between static lib such as .a and dynamic lib such as .dylib.   Because when I use boost, I just add the 'search' and the boost libs are all static(.a) and it works well. But when I use opencv2, there are a lot of dynamic libs(.dylib),if I don't add the 'link with binary', the compile will raise error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119708/dynamic-and-static-libraries-in-c and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140061/when-to-use-dynamic-vs-static-libraries

Comment: So I must add the dynamic library in the 'Link binary' to tell the compiler which dynamic library to link. And I can just need to add the static library in the 'Search', and the compiler will know which static library to link automatically. Is this right?

Comment: You can't add third party dynamic library for Apple will reject you application, but those within origin SDK is ok I think. So, If you want to add library, *General* - *Linked Frameworks and Libraries* so Here you go.